# Why does it say "DateTime does not exist"?

Tags: apex, date

**Apex Code**

```
public class TaskTriggerHelper {
   public TaskTriggerHelper(){

   }
   public static void createTask(list<Task> tskList){
    list<task> listOfTask = new list<task>();
    for(task tsk : tskList){
       DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(task.ActivityDate,0,0,0); 
    } 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the `newInstance` method, there are many signatures defined, but not the one you are trying to use:

> - **newInstance(milliseconds)**
>     Constructs a Datetime and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
> - **newInstance(date, time)**
>     Constructs a DateTime from the specified date and time in the local time zone.
> - **newInstance(year, month, day)**
>     Constructs a Datetime from Integer representations of the specified year, month (1=Jan), and day at midnight in the local time zone.
> - **newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)**
>     Constructs a Datetime from Integer representations of the specified year, month (1=Jan), day, hour, minute, and second in the local time zone.

If you already have a date, the simplest would be:

```
Datetime.newInstance(myDate, Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the error you are getting is:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
>   newInstance(Schema.SObjectField, Integer, Integer, Integer) from the
>   type Datetime

that is because you haven't defined the `task` variable so the compiler is assuming that `task.ActivityDate` is an SObjectField token (something that represents a field) rather than a field of an SObject instance.

Change `task.ActivityDate` to `tsk.ActivityDate`.